# NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate and CoreData

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicateeditor, nspredicateeditorrow

I am trying to generate predicate editor templates for my Core Data entities. In my code I have the following:

```
 NSEntityDescription *descrip = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
   NSArray *templates = [NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate templatesWithAttributeKeyPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"age", nil] inEntityDescription:descrip];

   [ibPredicateEditor setRowTemplates: templates];

   NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'John'"];

   [ibPredicateEditor setObjectValue:p];
```

Printing out the contents of the templates array gives me the following:

> CFArray 0x1002d7400 [0x7fff70ff5f20]
>   {type = immutable, count = 2, values =
>   (
>                  0 : NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate
>   0x10025c090: [name] [99, 4, 5, 8, 9]
>   NSStringAttributeType
>                  1 : NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate
>   0x1002d2dc0: [age] [4, 5, 0, 2, 1, 3]
>   NSInteger16AttributeType
>          )}

When this code executes I get the following on the console:

```
Warning - unable to find template matching predicate name LIKE "John"
```

The interface for doing this looks extremely straight forward, so I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

My original issue was that I was using the LIKE operator when my templates did not support it. However I am confused about why I get a similar warning when passing in a compound predicate into the editor.

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS 'John'"];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS 'Jo'"];
NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:p, p2, nil]];
[ibPredicateEditor setObjectValue: final];
```

**OR**

```
NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:p, p2, nil]];
[ibPredicateEditor setObjectValue: final];
```

Both of these produce similar warnings as my initial issue. However, I find it odd that I can use a single predicate and build a compound and predicate, but I can't pass a prebuilt  compound and predicate into the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default templates supplied by `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` for `NSString` key-paths do not support comparisons with the LIKE operator.

In the templates you generated there is a list of the operators it does support:

```
NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate 0x10025c090: [name] [99, 4, 5, 8, 9] NSStringAttributeType
```

`[99, 4, 5, 8, 9]` indicates that the name `NSString` attribute supports:

**4** – Equal To
**5** – Not Equal To
**8** – Begins With
**9** – Ends With
**99** – Contains

*(found in NSComparisonPredicate.h)*

CONTAINS is similar to LIKE without % and _ substitutions. If you require that you can always initialize your own template array.

*The syntax is **a bit** verbose.*

```
NSExpression *nameExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"name"];
NSArray *operators = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      [NSNumber numberWithInt: NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType],
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSNotEqualToPredicateOperatorType],
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSLikePredicateOperatorType],
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSBeginsWithPredicateOperatorType],
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSEndsWithPredicateOperatorType],
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSContainsPredicateOperatorType],
      nil];

NSUInteger options = (NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption |
                      NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption);

NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *template = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc]
      initWithLeftExpressions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameExpression]
      rightExpressionAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType
      modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
      operators:operators
      options:options];
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the LIKE operator. This code logs no warning:

```
NSPredicate *p;
p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'John'"];
[ibPredicateEditor setObjectValue:p];

p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age > 18"];
[ibPredicateEditor setObjectValue:p];
```

Comment: You are correct. As Ashely states above, the templates that are auto generated do not support the LIKE operator.